# Running update query with excel VBA - update error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to run an update query on an excel worksheet using the following code:

```
With db
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'; " & "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'"
    .Mode = adModeReadWrite
    .Open
End With

sql_str = "UPDATE [unload_data$] INNER JOIN [action_combos$] ON [unload_data$].action = [action_combos$].action1 " & _
        "AND [unload_data$].pick_ticket = [action_combos$].pick_ticket SET [unload_data$].conflict = [action_combos$].invalid "

db.Execute (sql_str)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and 
another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time
```

Now if I hard code a value in the SQL statement for `[unload_data$].conflict`  it works fine, but it won't update with the value from the field in the joint table. I have looked around online but so far haven't come up with any answer.

Comment: Why are you running an update query on a workbook? Just use Excel processes.

Comment: Hi Parfait, thanks for the response, I was doing that originally, however this portion is just a smaller portion of the overall code and doing it using a loop or excel function takes forever, since we are dealing with a large data set (unless I am misunderstanding what you mean by 'excel processes'). From other portions of the code I have switched to queries I have cut the processing time down by quite a bit, which is why I would have proffered to use Access for this project, but I can't.

Comment: I did however find out what is causing it, i have another update statement which runs before this one and I think it is causing some kind of lock because if i don't run that statement, the statement above runs just fine.

Comment: Try closing the `db` object or releasing it: `Set db = Nothing`. And yes, you should use MS Access, a better multiple user application and automation environment. Have that sit down with the boss!

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I have tried closing it and set it to nothing and then reopening it already, still no luck. Also now it will only run the SQL statement without error sometimes, its hit and miss. Time for that sit down I think :)